# Supporting mutilple Windows versions and SHA1/2 certificates for .exe (applications) and .sys (drivers)

Tags: windows, winapi, certificate, code-signing, signtool

Supporting older Windows versions in apps and drivers has become much more difficult due to MS policies/actions and Certificate Authorities (issuers) following them.  At this point it looks like we have to create our own self-signed SHA1 certificate and install that in the Trusted Publishers store on the end-users machine.  Also, cross-signing of drivers for OSes prior to Win10 is expired and no longer available as an option.  That means normal signing will need to be used and both the SHA2 and SHA1 certificate being added to the Trusted Publishers store on the end-user machine.

Catch 22 - while creating a mini certmgr type tool would be easy, there is no way to sign it for SHA1/SHA2 so the OS sees a valid signature before installing the certificates to the store.  Had this utility been created a couple years it could have been signed with the SHA1/SHA2 certificates that worked at that time.  certmgr (SDK 8.1) however is double-signed with SHA1/SHA2...

Now the question I have is if we were to sign the apps with the valid SHA2 EV certificate and the SHA1 self-signed certificate so that the SHA2 EV is "valid" (on Win Vista or later) and the SHA1 is "invalid" (because certificate is not in the store) will that throw off Anti-virus software or Windows itself or are they smart enough to see the SHA2 EV is "valid" so it's valid?

Same with drivers (on OSes prior to win10) (Win10 are signed by MS and while the SHA2 signature is good, the .cat file has no reference to prior OS versions - only Win10/11 are available in the MS portal)?  Although drivers wouldn't be installed prior to installation of the certificate.

The question comes up because we would like to only install the SHA1 certificate to the store on old OSes (Prior to Vista) that may still use SHA1 and leave it off the newer OS versions (meaning it's invalid)?  But we wonder what problems / confusion with other software / Windows could that create?

Comment: Since Windows can simply ignore SHA1, it seems there should have been no reason to prevent the CA's from issuing SHA1 certificates to make it easy to support the old OS.  The same applies to the cross-signing of drivers, new versions of Windows could simply ignore those and only support the MS signed version (like it already does for Win10/11 - this would allow updates to drivers for Win7, etc..).  These changes are what everyone was worried about when all the certificate requirement stuff was being proposed.  They ensured everyone this wouldn't happen...

Comment: If all else fails, create two versions and decide during install. Upgrading Windows could break this if moving from a SHA1 to a SHA2 system.

Comment: There might be a hotfix for older OS to support SHA2.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work with normal signing Win7/Vista drivers, if not cross-signed and the certificates are in the store, it still won't work unless the system is put in testing mode.  Bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON